# Consultar dados no banco de acordo com a data

Tags: php, mysql

Consultar dados no mysql nos últimos 3 dias, ou seja, exibir dados do banco do dia 15 até hoje (17/02/2014)

Estou usando assim:

```
$condicaoData = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("-3 days"));
$selecionaTabela = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noticias
                   WHERE data >= '$condicaoData' ORDER BY id DESC")or die(mysql_error());
```

Mas está vindo dados do mês de janeiro também, ou seja, o mês não está contando, apenas o dia.

Comment: O campo data é `date` ?

Comment: Se eu entendi corretamente seu problema, fica minha resposta, abraços!

Comment: Lembre-se de escolher a melhor resposta. Você faz diversas perguntas e quem responde gosta de ter um feedback também. Abraço.

Answer (score 2):

Supondo que `data` esteja no formato `DATE`, `DATETIME` ou `TIMESTAMP`, `$condicaoData` deve estar no formato `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Vocẽ pode fazer duas coisas: fornecer a data no formato recebido e usar a função `DATE_FORMAT` do MySQL ou transformar a data recebida no formato exigido pelo MySQL.

Para usar a função `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
$sql = "
     SELECT *
     FROM noticias
     WHERE data >= DATE_FORMAT('$condicaoData', '%d/%m/%Y')
     ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Para transformar o formato recebido no formato do MySQL:

```
// caso você possa gerar a data no formato Y-m-d
$condicaoData = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-3 days"));

// ou caso você já tenha a data no formato d/m/Y
$condicaoData = preg_replace(
    '/^(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)$/',
    '$3-$2-$1',
    date('d/m/Y', $condicaoData));
```

E então o SQL seria:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM noticias
    WHERE data >= '$condicaoData'
    ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Outra dica: considere a possibilidade de usar [Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), que é a opção mais segura para proteger seu banco de dados contra ataques do tipo SQL injection. Assim a query fica em cache no seu banco e as únicas coisas que alteram são os parâmetros – no caso, as datas da sua query.

Answer (score 1):

No [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) as datas são por padrão salvas no formato `YYYY-MM-DD`, tanto para `DATE`, `DATETIME` ou `TIMESTAMP` como pode ser visto na [documentação do MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)
Neste caso tente o seguinte código:

```
$condicaoData = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-3 days"));
$selecionaTabela = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noticias
                   WHERE data >= '{$condicaoData}' ORDER BY id DESC")or die(mysql_error());
```

Observação: inseri "{}" na variável `$condicaoData` pois alguns servidores não interpretam corretamente uma variável diretamente dentro de uma `string` (se mal configurado principalmente) e isso garante que sua variável vá ser lida corretamente.

Comment: No php é `Y` para representar o ano com 4 digitos lembre que `m`é diferente de `M` . [php date](http://br1.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)

Comment: Estava olhando a referência do MySql antes de terminar de editar, obrigado pela correção @perdeu.

Answer (score 0):

Você nem precisa usar a variável **$condicaoData**, usando a função NOW() do MySQL para capturar a momento atual e a função DATE_SUB() para subtrair um determinado intervalo da data. 
Veja os exemplo abaixo:

Para garantir que pegará exatamente do momento atual até -3 dias.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM noticias ".
         "WHERE (data BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) AND NOW()) ".
         "ORDER BY id DESC";
$selecionaTabela = mysql_query($query);
```

Caso você tenha certeza que não existem registros com a data superior à data do momento atual, você pode buscar assim também:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM noticias ".
         "WHERE data >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)) ".
         "ORDER BY id DESC";
$selecionaTabela = mysql_query($query);
```

Funções MySQL (w3schools.com):
- [NOW()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp)
- [DATE_SUB()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp)

Funções MySQL (dev.mysql.com):
- [NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)
- [DATE_SUB()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso
MONTH = http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php

YEAR = http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-year-function.php

```
$condicaoData = date('d/m/Y', strtotime("-3 days"));
$selecionaTabela = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM noticias
                   WHERE data >= '$condicaoData' AND MONTH(CURDATE())=MONTH(data) AND YEAR(CURDATE())=YEAR(data)  ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: @user3081 dá uma olhada nessa aqui..