# Exibir dados no intervalo de uma semana mySql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-select

Estou criando um código que irá mostrar a tabua de maré, tenho uma tabela com os seguintes campos: Date - Time - TideHeight

Ela já esta toda preenchida, preciso fazer uma consulta e selecionar os dados da semana, como o dia, a hora e a altura da maré.

Como funciona no [site da marinha](http://www.mar.mil.br/dhn/chm/box-previsao-mare/tabuas/).

Escrevi o código abaixo, preciso que ela exiba a semana atual, ou um intervalo de 7 dias de hoje para frente.

```
//semana atual
$data = date('W');

// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tidedata WHERE WEEK(date) = '$data'"); 

echo "Tide for week:<br/>";

while ($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    echo $array["date"]." ".$array["time"]." ".$array["tideheight"]."<br/>";

}
```

Como faço para exibir os dados da tabela no intervalo de uma semana, exibindo o dia, a hora e altura da maré?

**Resolvi esse problema da seguinte maneira:**

```
//semana atual
$semana = date('W');
$ano = date('Y');

// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tidedata WHERE WEEK(date) = '$semana' AND YEAR(date) = '$ano'"); 

echo "Tide for week:<br/>";

while ($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        echo $array["date"]." ".$array["time"]." ".$array["tideheight"]."<br/>";

}
```

Se alguém tiver uma outra solução pode postar abaixo.

Comment: Pra começar o seu código tem um erro: você seta a variável **$data** e consulta no banco com uma variável que não existe, **$date**. Conserta isso e vê o que dá na sua aplicação.

Comment: Percebi isso também, estou fazendo as alterações necessárias.

Comment: Existem functions como WEEK e WEEKOFYEAR que podem ser úteis.

Comment: Veja se alguma dessas questões ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9296/ | http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14653/ | http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16600/ | http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6073/ | http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4177/ | http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30891/ | http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29997/